# Let $A = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Show that there is a bijection from ${\cal P}(A)$ with the cartesian product $X^n$ where $X = \{0, 1\}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am in need of hints in proving this. I am unsure if this can be done using mathematical induction.

Comment: Try constructing a bijection $f:A\rightarrow X^n$ for $n=1$ and then for $n=2$, and see if you can observe a natural pattern from the $n$ case to the $(n+1)$-case. Trying the basic cases usually helps to get some familiarity.

Comment: Is there some particular reason for you to use induction? IMV that is not such a good idea here.